# Ektron PageBuilder - define default name for custom widget

Tags: ektron

I'm hoping this is a simple question.  I have a custom widget.  Let's say it is "SuperAwesomeWidget.ascx". When I'm editing a PageBuilder wireframe, I can see my widget in the little pulldown widget tray at the top of the screen.  Thing is, the name under my icon is "SuperAwesomeWidget".

Now, I know that I can go to the widgets settings in the WorkArea and define a custom name, but what if I want Ektron to just "know" what the name should be?  I'm hoping there is some config file somewhere that I can add my widget name to.  I'd like to be able to drop this widget along with maybe a config file or something into a second Ektron install and not need to define the name via the workarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone in the future googling this issue, there is a better answer than my previous one, particularly better than a workarea modification.

To update the display title of a widget in the widget bar:

1. Go to Workarea > Settings > Configuration > Personalization > Widgets
2. Find your widget in this list and click the edit icon to the left of its name
3. Modify the display title in the second text field in the modal that pops up.

Confirmed working in 8.6.1, likely works in all 8+ versions.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: While this answer is still partially correct, I have discovered the actual way to do this. The correction has been marked as the accepted answer.

Set your `IWidgethost`'s title property:

```
IWidgetHost _host;
...
_host.Title = "Hello World Widget";
```

From the esteemed eGandalf's tutorial on widget development:
http://www.ektron.com/Blogs/eGandalf/Break-it-down!-Widget-Development-How-To-(Part-1)/

Comment: I was hoping this would also affect the widget title as shown by the repeater in `/Workarea/PageBuilder/PageControls/WidgetTray.ascx` but it doesn't seem to be doing that.  Setting the **Title** property on `IWidgetHost` does change the text shown in the black region above the widget after it has been dragged into a dropzone's column.

Comment: Hm - seems like an inconsistency on ektron's part. I guess that's what evil workarea modifications are for!